# getting File Not Found Error when downloading media with requests and inserting variable for filename

Tags: python, python-requests

My script for downloading media files works fine if I hard code a filename into the final lines, but if I try to use the variable 'filename' since I'm downloading multiple files, I get the error:

```
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

For example, this works:

```
    with open ('test.csv', 'r') as list_file:
list_reader = csv.DictReader(list_file, delimiter = ',')
for row in list_reader:
        media_id = row['mediaId']
        filename = row['key']

        saveFile = media.get_item(media_id)

        stream_url = saveFile['streams'][0]['streamLocation']

        r = requests.get(stream_url, allow_redirects=True)

        with open('media/x.wav ', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
```

but it doesn't work if I do:

```
        with open(os.path.join('./media/', filename), 'wb') as ofile:
            ofile.write(r.content)
```

and DOES work if I do the following although of course the problem is it only saves one file:

```
        with open(os.path.join('./media/', 'x.wav'), 'wb') as ofile:
            ofile.write(r.content)
```

What is the syntax I need to fix here?

Comment: `print` statements are your friend, use it to compare the different filenames that you generate.

Comment: `filename` probably starts with a slash, which makes that `os.path.join` throw away its first argument completely

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the reason it didn't work was that the url filename had so many forward slashes in it. When I removed those it worked fine.

Comment: Right, that's how `os.path.join` works: (quote from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)) "If a component is an absolute path, _all previous components are thrown away_ and joining continues from the absolute path component"